# Center label and textfield in view using IB

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, autoresize

I have a question that is hopefully very basic to answer. I have a view that I created in IB that has 3 labels and 3 textfields. Each are place in the left, center, and right side of the view. The view that these objects are placed in autoresizes itself when a second view needs to come into focus so that the two views are now sharing a screen.

The issue I am having is when this view resizes itself the left and the right labels and text boxes automatically align properly with each other, however, the controls in the center get overlapped by the right control. Is there any way, particularly through IB, can I anchor the control to the center of the view so that when the view gets resized the center control will always be in the center?

Thanks in advance